# How to determine if logical expressions are equivalent or not

Tags: c, logic

I do not know how to test this using a truth table because I haven't been taught that yet. Can someone explain if the expression  !(a < b)  the same as  !a >= !b ?

Comment: no you reverse it 2 times here. `!(a<b)` is equal to `(a >= b)`

Comment: Something like `!var` can be dangerous because you're trying to evaluate a non-boolean value as if it were a logical boolean expression.  On most systems what this will in effect do is `!var` will evaluate to `false` if `var` is anything but zero.  Even if that's what you want, it's dangerous because not all systems are guaranteed to respond in this manner--it's hardware dependent.  A safer expression would be to evaluate your variable against zero (e.g. `if ( var == 0 )`).

Answer (score 0):

Expression `(a < b)` is logical expression. We can say about it that it is **true** or it is **false**. `(a < b) is true` for example when `a = 1` and `b = 3`. Otherwise, `(a < b) is false` when `a = b` or for example, when `a = 5` and `b = 2`.

`!(expression)` -- is unary logical operator **NOT** which is **true** when expression is false, and it is **false** when expression is true.

So, when you write `!(a < b)` logically it means `NOT (a < b)`, so it is `(a >= b)`.

In C you can use unary operator `!`. The result of the logical negation operator `!` is `1` if the value of its operand is zero, and `0` if the value of its operand is nonzero. The type of the result is `int`. The logical negation operator is applicable to any arithmetic type and to pointers.

So, technically, syntax of expression `(!a >= !b)` is correct, but from logical point of view its nonsense in your case.